# Trying to search along the multi dimensional array adn print out the desired output

Tags: php, arrays

I am learning about arrays in PHP. I am working on multidimensional arrays in which I am facing an issue. i want to print the output base on the venue and date also.

Here is an illustration of sample multidimensional array:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [venue] => chicago
            [course] => science
            [time] => 2pm
            [date]=>jan2016-feb-2017

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
             [venue] => newyork
            [course] => robotics
            [time] =>3pm
            [date]=>jan2016-feb-2017
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [venue] => newyork
            [course] => science
            [time] => 4pm
              [date]=>mar2017-feb-2018
        )
     [3] => Array
        (
            [venue] => chicago
            [course] => robtics
            [time] => 4pm
            [date]=>mar2017-feb-2018
        )
 [4] => Array
        (
            [venue] => chicago
            [course] => robotics
            [time] => 2pm
            [date]=>jan2016-feb-2017

        )
  [5] => Array
        (
            [venue] => chicago
            [course] => science
            [time] => 4pm
            [date]=>mar2017-feb-2018

        )
 [6] => Array
        (
             [venue] => newyork
            [course] => robotics
            [time] =>1pm
            [date]=>mar2017-feb-2018
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [venue] => newyork
            [course] => science
            [time] => 5pm
              [date]=>mar2017-feb-2018
        )

)
```

Here is the desired output i want :

```
chicago
Date:jan2016-feb-2017
science  2pm
robotics  2pm 

chicago
Date:mar2017-feb-2018
science  4pm
robotics  4pm 


newyork 
Date:jan2016-feb-2017
science 4pm
robotics 3pm 

newyork 
Date:mar2017-feb-2018
science 5pm
robotics 1pm
```

i want to print the output base on the venue and date also.please  help me guys

My current code :

```
usort($events, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['venue'], $b['venue']);
});
$previousVenue = null;
foreach ($events as $event) {

    // check if this venue is the same as the previous, output header if not
    if ($event['venue'] != $previousVenue) {
        echo "<h3>$event[venue]</h3>";
        echo "$event[date]";
    }
    // always output course and time
    echo "$event[course] $event[time]<br>";

    // current venue becomes previous venue
    $previousVenue = $event['venue'];
}
```

I am managed to search it with venue but i am not able to print it according to date.

Comment: What is your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) or [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort your multidimensional array based one or many keys. E.g. you can sort it based on venue and date respectively, and then just iterate over the result and print it out.

```
uasort($events, function($a, $b) {
    $venueComparison = strcmp($a['venue'], $b['venue']);
    if (!$venueComparison) {
        return compare_date($a['date'], $b['date']);
    }
});

foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo '...';
}
```

Or you could iterate over your multidimensional array and transform it into a more suitable structure.

```
$groupedEvents = array();
foreach ($events as $event) {
    if (!array_key_exists($event['venue'], $groupedEvents)) {
        $groupedEvents[$event['venue']] = array();
    }
    $groupedEvents[$event['venue']][] = $event;
}

foreach ($groupedEvents as $venue => $events) {
    usort($events, 'compare_date');
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        echo '...';
    }
}
```

Either way, you would need something which parses your date ranges, and sorts them. You will both need to do the parsing by your own and then decided on if you are going to sort by the start date or the end date.

Or, if possible, you could switch to a more easily sortable date range format. E.g. ISO 8601.

One shot is to split [strotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on the first part of your date and just compare the resulting timestamps. Something like this:

```
function compare_date($a, $b) {
    return strtotime(substr($a, 0, strpos($a, '-'))) - strtotime(substr($b, 0, strpos($b, '-')));
}
```

Comment: i used but i am not able to print it according to date

Comment: I revised by answer with a solution on how to sort your date format. Does this work for you?

Comment: it didn't work can you share your output or can you explain you answer more

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the date something that we can "order" on. If you do that you could just run the usort again. (the php7 way btw). Hope this is helpfull...edit, kinda messy code but maybe you get it :) Cheers

```
   /*-----( example array )------*/
        $arr =  array(
           array(
               'venue' => 'chicago',
               'course' => 'science',
               'time' => '2pm',
               'date' => 'jan2016-feb-2017',
           ),
           array(
               'venue' => 'amsterdam',
               'course' => 'science',
               'time' => '4pm',
               'date' => 'jan2016-feb-2017',
           ),
           array(
               'venue' => 'chicago',
               'course' => 'science',
               'time' => '2pm',
               'date' => 'jan2016-feb-2017',
           ),
        );

        /*-----( remove dublicates )-----*/
        $s = array_map('serialize', $arr);
        $u = array_unique($s);
        $arr = array_intersect_key($arr, $u);

        /*-----( sort based on venue)------*/
        usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
            return $a['venue'] <=> $b['venue'];
        });

        /*----( edit, order on dates )----*/
        foreach($arr as $k => $a)
        {
            $t = explode('-',$a['date']);
            $arr[$k]['t_date'] = isset($t[0]) ? $t[0] :null;
        }

        usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
            return $a['t_date'] <=> $b['t_date'];
        });

        /*----( output )----*/
        foreach($arr as $a)
        {
            foreach($a as $k => $v)
            {
                echo $k == 'venue' ? $v : $k.' '.$v;
                echo '<br>';
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
```